# Design Question - Changing SQL query in my SSIS package using C# code

Tags: c#, ssis

I have a basic question for which I am not able to find a help. I have few SSIS packages developed (not deployed) and I need to change some part of SQL command text based on customer needs. As this will change dynamically, I was planning to write a C# code  and change it as and when required. 
Is this possible? if yes, any link would be appreciated.

Comment: Create `Configuration file` where you will save the query and read the query from text file using C# or else create a table where the customer will dynamically enter the SQL  and then read the query from this table

Comment: Query is not entered by customer. It is generated in scripts. The place where it is generated, we are unable to change it hence we thought to change the query after the packages are generated and queries reside in them. Hope I am clear.